# Koa cannot response with object

Tags: node.js, object, response, koa

As I know from api, ctx.body could be Object || Array json-stringified. There is no problems with array, but I can't response with object, only blank one {}. If I have somthing inside such as key/value, for example {foo: 'bar'} browser has no response data available. But if I put it in array it's ok. What is it?

Comment: Trying to reproduce the error, in my koa api I forced the body to be ctx.body = {foo: 'bar'}; and got the following response in postman: {"foo": "bar"}

Comment: Could you please share a code stub?